# How To Make smiley panel in c#

Tags: c#

I have a RichTextBox in my project which is for Jabber chatroom where i get all chat of users and maself.

I want to embed smileys in my project.i want a panel containing all smileys.and when click any smiley it must be sent.

like :) displays smile face
:@ is angry face

They must be shown in richtextbox also in form of smiley not symbols like :)

How can i do this in c#.

I had found this code on stack overflow.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.SuspendLayout();

    List<Bitmap> Smiles = new List<Bitmap>(); //Add images

    ToolStripSplitButton _toolStripSplitButton = new ToolStripSplitButton();
    _toolStripSplitButton.Size = new Size(23, 23);
    //_toolStripSplitButton.Image = myImage; //Add the image of the stripSplitButton

    ToolStrip _toolStrip = new ToolStrip();
    _toolStrip.Size = new Size(ClientSize.Width, 10);
    _toolStrip.Location = new Point(0, this.ClientSize.Height - _toolStrip.Height);
    _toolStrip.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    _toolStrip.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
    _toolStrip.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { _toolStripSplitButton });

    SmileBox smilebox = new SmileBox(new Point(_toolStripSplitButton.Bounds.Location.X, _toolStrip.Location.Y - 18), 6);
    smilebox.Visible = false;

    Controls.Add(smilebox);

    foreach (Bitmap bmp in Smiles)
        smilebox.AddItem(bmp);

    _toolStripSplitButton.Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        smilebox.Visible = true;
    });

    Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        smilebox.Visible = false;
    });

    this.Controls.Add(_toolStrip);
    this.ResumeLayout();
}

void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
}

 class SmileBox : Panel
{
    public List<Item> Items
{
    get;
    set;
}

Size _ItemSpace = new Size(20, 20);
Point _ItemLocation;
int _rowelements = 0;

    public SmileBox(Point Location, int RowElements)
{
    BackColor = Color.LightGray;

    Height = _ItemSpace.Height;
    Width = _ItemSpace.Width * RowElements;

    this.Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y - Height);
    _ItemLocation = new Point(0, 0);
    _rowelements = RowElements;
}

int count = 1;
public void AddItem(Bitmap Image)
{
    Item item = new Item(_ItemSpace, _ItemLocation, Image);

    if (_ItemLocation.X + _ItemSpace.Width >= Width)
        _ItemLocation = new Point(0, _ItemLocation.Y);
    else
        _ItemLocation = new Point(_ItemLocation.X + _ItemSpace.Width, _ItemLocation.Y);

    if (count == _rowelements)
    {
        _ItemLocation = new Point(_ItemLocation.X, _ItemLocation.Y + _ItemSpace.Height);
        Height += _ItemSpace.Height;
        Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y - _ItemSpace.Height);

        count = 0;
    }

    count++;

    Controls.Add(item);
}
}

 class Item : PictureBox
{
int _BorderSpace = 2;

public Item(Size Size, Point Location, Bitmap Image)
{
    this.Size = new Size(Size.Width - 2 * _BorderSpace, Size.Height - 2 * _BorderSpace);
    this.Location = new Point(Location.X + _BorderSpace, Location.Y + _BorderSpace);
    this.Image = new Bitmap(Image, this.ClientSize);

    Click += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here what do you want to do when the user click on the smile
    });

    MouseEnter += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Focus();
        Invalidate();
    });
}

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus();
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}

protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invalidate();
    base.OnEnter(e);
}

protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invalidate();
    base.OnLeave(e);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    base.OnPaint(pe);

    if (this.Focused)
    {
        ClientRectangle.Inflate(-1, -1);
        Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;
        ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(pe.Graphics, rect);
    }
}
}
```

The above code is not working for me as its too messy to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - this guy has written exactly the same:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R

Comment: [Link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) are not extremely helpful if the link goes dead at some point.